# How to inject bean to configuration overriden method

Tags: java, spring

I'm using spring and want to implement some java-configuration in my application.
Here is spring's abstract config, for example

```java
@Configuration
class AbstactConfiguration {
  protected void configureSettings(Builder builder) {}
}
```

And my implementation
I want to setup some injected collection in configureSettings method, so I've done field injection to configuration class, since I can't add this field as argument to override method

```java
class ConfigurationImpl extends AbstactConfiguration {
  @Autowired(required = false)
  Collection<Something> collection;

  @Override
  protected void configureSettings(Builder builder) {
     builder.addCollection(collection)
  }
}
```

Am I doing it right? Because I got warning: `Field injection is not recommended`

Comment: create a constructor of `ConfigurationImpl` that takes `Collection<Something> collection` as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a constructor of ConfigurationImpl and it must has "Collection<>" as an input. So you can inject bean from another class.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).